# Visualforce error when creating a apex:repeat on a selectoption

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Okay, I've been banging my head trying to figure out how to get around this issue without writing unnecessary code.

I have the following Visualforce code that is causing a error when saving:

```
<select id="rec_count">
    <apex:repeat value="{!pg}" var="selpg">
        <option {!IF(selpg.value = selectedpgtxt, 'selected','')} value="{!selpg.value}" >
              {!selpg.value}
        </option>
    </apex:repeat>
</select>
```

The error is:
**Error: Element type "option" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".**

Apparently the visual force parser is upset about a option tag not having a attribute for the `{!IF(selpg.value = selectedpgtxt, 'selected','')}`.

I have tried the equivalent of:

```
<option selected="" value="1">1</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">2</option>
```

However browser considers all of the options selected doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless this is considered unnecessary code, the following seems pretty straightforward to me.

Visualforce:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!theSelection}">
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!theList}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Apex:

```
// Top of class
public List<SelectOption> theList {get; private set;}
public String theSelection {get; set;}


// In constructor
this.theList = new List<SelectOption>();
this.theList.add(new SelectOption('1', 'First Option'));
this.theList.add(new SelectOption('2', 'Second Option'));

// Now for the default
this.theSelection = '1';
```

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I didn't use the apex:selectlist in the first place.  Guess I just got tunnel vision on fixing the <option> issue.

Comment: No problem. I usually try to find the "Force.com approved path" to get things done, if there is one, since time and again I've found myself in the weeds trying to get JavaScript/CSS/HTML to do what Force.com provides natively. Id/name mangling in the Visualforce pre-processor really throws people off as well (see $Component: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global.htm).